# Browser automation in .Net

Tags: silverlight, selenium, browser, automation, xbap

Can I automate actions like filling and submitting a form, clicking links et.c. in a real browser (i.e. IE11 or Firefox) using only a Silverlight or an XBAP application?

I would be grateful if you could let me know any other solution (other than the two above) that can do the automations without the need to manually install third party software (like Selenium or Telerik Testing Framework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one answered, so I'll tell you what worked and what not.

Silverlight solutions didn't work due to the [Same-origin browser policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

The XBAP solution actually worked. I created a new XBAP application and loaded it in my other application inside an iframe.

The user must accept the pop-up and the XBAP application opens a new WebBrowser control doing its stuff.

The whole thing only supports IE.